# SSH backup server - connect to multiple passwordless remotes

Tags: ssh, public-key, private-key

I'm wondering what are the steps to configure password-less ssh keys so I can connect and pull data from multiple remote servers. Can I just do:

**Backup Machine:**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@server1
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@server2
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@server3
```

and on each remote server{1-3} do:

```
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
```

and let `rsync` pull the data from the backup server to each remote.

Would those be the correct steps?

Thanks

Comment: Are you rolling your own backup solution or using something like dirvish?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the generate command as root (via `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`) so the key isn't in your home directory
2. You can't `ssh`/`scp` to your servers as root if you don't have interactive root login (e.g. on Debian-based systems); do it as your user, assuming you have a login on those machines. Then login and copy the authorized_keys file into `/root/.ssh/` on each server and set the correct permissions.
3. Use a `from="w.x.y.z"` stanza in your authorized_keys file if you have a static IP on your backup machine. The `PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only` isn't really much better than `without-password`.

Comment: thanks for the tips, though, not sure what do you mean with interactive login? All machines are running Debian.

Comment: @JoshyD you're trying to scp the public key to your remote machine as root, which will ask for a password (interactive login), which doesn't exist. I'll clarify my answer to suggest copying it as your own user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.theinternets.be/laptop-backups-with-dirvish/) on this a while back (it's based around setting up dirvish, which is an rsync based backup system). Once you setup the keys on the clients you can run a backup, see what command it runs, and then set forced-commands.